# REST GET call in VBA is returning "data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available"

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I am working on REST API calls from excel vba to my database and I am having trouble with a particular GET call with a parameter. The error is " Run-time error '-2147483638 (80000000a)': The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available".

Previously in one of the environments, I was able to get around it by putting in an Application.wait of 40 seconds. But I have another environment which is even slower and no amount of wait time is resulting in data populated in the .responseText. Out of vba, the call works in 50 seconds so I tried 50 up to 8 minutes with no luck. Any idea on how to get this GET call to work in this slower environment?

Below is the code I am using:

```
URL = ".../?q=%7B%22testid%22:%22" & vSAMPLE_ID & "%22%7D"        
        http.Open "GET", URL, True
        http.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        http.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "application/json"
        http.send
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:20"))
        vRESTRESPONSE = http.ResponseText
```

Comment: You want  http.Open "GET", URL, False possibly

Comment: I tried that out and It timed out on the http.send line. What does that mean?

Comment: Are you sure your url is correct?

Comment: I am able to print the url and paste it into the browser and that works so I think so.

Answer (score 0):

could you not request asynchronously, so it doesn't matter how long you have to wait for a response? (as long as the server doesn't timeout the request) 
Or is the next steps dependant on a response from this request?

Comment: Yes, the next step is dependent on the response of this query.

Comment: They are already requesting async by virtue of True argument.

Comment: The True statement on http.Open makes it asynchronous so that the send and .responseText don't happen at the same time?